# Will this give me proper random numbers based on these probabilities? C++

Tags: c++, random, probability

Code:

```
int random = (rand() % 7 + 1)
if (random == 1) { } // num 1
else if (random == 2) { } // num 2
else if (random == 3 || random == 4) { } // num 3
else if (random == 5 || random == 6) { } // num 4
else if (random == 7) { } // num 5
```

Basically I want each of these numbers with each of these probabilities:
1: 1/7
2: 1/7
3: 2/7
4: 2/7
5: 1/7

Will this code give me proper results? I.e. if this is run infinite times, will I get the proper frequencies? Is there a less-lengthy way of doing this?

Comment: Use a switch instead, with cases for the seven numbers.

Comment: does "proper" imply "unpredictable, unique random noise" or just "statistically okish"?

Comment: Just statistically ok is what I'm trying to get at :)

Comment: If `RAND_MAX` is `32768`, you'll get a distribution of (roughly) `4682/32768, 4681/32768, 9362/32768, 9362/32768, 4681/32768`.  Which is within 0.03% of your intended frequencies.  Is that statistically ok? (note the first two are different)

Comment: Also, `RAND_MAX` is usually quite a bit larger, making the accuracy higher.

Comment: @MooingDuck, define "usually". Microsoft uses 0x7fff for RAND_MAX, and their compiler is pretty widely used.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Oh, I thought MSVC had 0xFFFF.  My mistake.

Comment: If you throw away any result from rand() that are greater than `RAND_MAX-(RANDMAX%7)` then using %7 should give you an even distribution.

Answer (score 7):

Not, it's actually slightly off, due to the way rand() works. In particular, rand returns values in the range [0,RAND_MAX]. Hypothetically, assume RAND_MAX were ten. Then rand() would give 0…10, and they'd be mapped (by modulus) to:

```
0  → 0
1  → 1
2  → 2
3  → 3
4  → 4
5  → 5
6  → 6
7  → 0
8  → 1
9  → 2
10 → 3
```

Note how 0–3 are more common than 4–6; this is bias in your random number generation. (You're adding 1 as well, but that just shifts it over).

RAND_MAX of course isn't 10, but it's probably not a multiple of 7 (minus 1), either. Most likely its a power of two. So you'll have some bias.

I suggest using the [Boost Random Number Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/random/index.html) which can give you a random number generator that yields 1–7 without bias. Look also at [bames53's answer using C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317726/27727), which is the right way to do this if your code only needs to target C++11 platforms.

Comment: The bias due to this is likely to be pretty small. Assuming `rand()` is good and the maximum value is a more realistic 2^32 - 1 the bias toward each of the lower four values will be about 7e-8 percent. The quality of the implementation of `rand()` is going to have a much bigger impact.

Comment: @bames53: Well, sometimes RAND_MAX is only 2¹⁵-1 or often 2³¹-1. 2³²-1 is impossible with 32-bit ints (which is normal even on 64-bit machines, where long is often the 64-bit type). But the boost generators are (a) easy to use; (b) don't have this bias; (c) should be at least as fast; (d) you don't have to worry about bad C library implementations of rand().

Comment: derobert, The bias is still tiny with RAND_MAX being 2^31 - 1 and even with 2^15 - 1 it's only 0.003 percent. Boost is a reasonable alternative if C++11 isn't available (see my answer for C++11 examples, which may also translate to boost).

Comment: @bames53: Your C++11 examples are indeed good. I've upvoted them. But with both Boost and C++11 providing unbiased (and probably faster) generators, there isn't any reason to accept bias, even if its tiny. Might as well get in the habit of doing it right.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way:

```
float probs[5] = {1/7.0f, 1/7.0f, 2/7.0f, 2/7.0f, 1/7.0f};
float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  sum += probs[i]; /* edit */
int rand_M() {
  float f = (rand()*sum)/RAND_MAX; /* edit */
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (f <= probs[i]) return i;
    f -= probs[i];
  }
  return 4;
}
```

Comment: That biases in favor of the last element doesn't it?  Due to rounding errors in the probabilities when summed?

Comment: I got it closer, but still no: http://ideone.com/PG68c.  floats round.  Adding them compounds it.  It gives the second to last number _slightly_ too much likelyhood by ~.00000003, and the last too little by ~-.00000004.

Answer (score 2):

```
int toohigh = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX%7;
int random;
do { 
    random = rand();
while (random >= toohigh); //should happen ~0.03% of the time
static const int results[7] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5};
random = results[random%7];
```

This should give numbers with a distribution as even as `rand` can handle, and without the big `if` switch.

Note this does have a theoretically possible infinite loop, but the statistical odds of it staying in the loop for even are minuscule.  The odds of it staying in the loop *twice* is quite close to the odds of winning the California Super Lotto Jackpot.  Even if every person on the planet got five random numbers, it probably wouldn't stay in the loop three times. (Assuming a perfect RNG.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `rand()` is good then your code will work with only a very small bias to the lower X numbers, where X is RAND_MAX % 7. It's much more likely that you won't get the desired odds due to the quality of the implementation of `rand()`. If you find that to be the case then you'll want to use an alternative random number generator.

C++11 introduces the header `<random>` which includes several quality RNGs. Here's an example:

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>

auto rand = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1,7),std::mt19937());
```

Given this, when you call `rand()` you will get a number from 1 to 7 each with equal probability. (And you can choose different engines if for different quality and speed characteristics.) You can then use this to implement the if-else conditions your example currently uses with `std::rand()`. However `<random>` allows you to do even better using one of their non-uniform distributions. In this case what you want is `discrete_distribution`. This distribution allows you to explicitly state the weights for each value from 0 to n.

```
// the random number generator
auto _rand = std::bind(std::discrete_distribution<int>{1./7.,1./7.,2./7.,2./7.,1./7.},std::mt19937());
// convert results of RNG from the range [0-4] to [1-5]
auto rand = [&_rand]() { return _rand() +1; };
```

Comment: whoa, didn't realize MSVC added these already! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926127.aspx

Answer (score -1):

[rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) returns *pseudo*-random integral number:

> Notice though that this modulo operation **does not generate a truly
>   uniformly distributed random number** in the span (since in most cases
>   **lower numbers are slightly more likely**), but it is generally a good
>   approximation for short spans.

---

Now, regarding the less-lengthy way, you can use switch-case construction, or a series of [conditional operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) `?:` (which will make your code short and unreadable:).