# how to represent these kind of probabilities in C++?

Tags: c++

I have found some probabilities whose sum doesn't give 1, note these probabilities don't have to give 1

So I have something like this

```
0.00112
0.12311
0.3933393
0.111010
0.0002
0.003
0.00000000004
```

etc.

Now I'm trying to use these probabilities in my application.

What I did is I found their normalized form, so I found the sum and then I get these probabilities

```
0.00177277097
0.194862351
0.622589724
0.175710094
0.000316566244
0.00474849366
6.33132488 × 10^(-11)
```

Their sum gives 1 as a result

Now I'm thinking of using an array of 1,000,000 places, where I will put for example for the first probability 0.00177277097*1,000,000 places that will have the value for the probability and do the same thing for the others

The thing is I can lose some points if I use this method, for example maybe in the end I will have 999,994 places filled and not 1,000,000..

Is there any other method that can be used in this case?

Comment: Why are you making an array like that?  How are you planning to use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8316819/390913

Comment: I vaguely recall the random number generator returning a double between 0 and 1 anyway, so you can just use these values to segment that range. If it ends up being outside the set of possibilities (because they don't sum to 1), just try again.

Comment: I would use a rand function then that would give me a value from 1 to 1000, I would use that index to pick the value that is in the array..

Comment: Please do not place your array on the stack.  Thank you @your compiler

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the purpose of the 1,000,000 element array is to randomly pick one of the seven elements in a non-linear distribution with (at least) six decimal digits of accuracy, there's easier ways to do that.

You showed you could normalize the probabilities to sum to 1 (good!), so step one would be to normalize them to integers summing to 1,073,741,824 (2^30):

```
0.00112       ->   1903498.331       ->   1903498
0.12311       -> 209231856.7         -> 209231857
0.3933393     -> 668500626.0         -> 668500626
0.111010      -> 188667276.5         -> 188667276  (I rounded this down)
0.0002        ->    339910.4162      ->    339910
0.003         ->   5098656.244       ->   5098656
0.00000000004 ->         0.067982083 ->         1  (I rounded this up)
```

and put their sums into an array:

```
static const int dist[7] = {1903498, 
                            211135355, 
                            879635981, 
                            1068303257, 
                            1068643167, 
                            1073741823, 
                            1073741824}; //last should be 1073741824
```

and then to pick a random one with your distribution:

```
element getrandom(element data[7]) {
    int r = ((rand() * RAND_MAX) ^ rand()) & 0x3FFFFFFF; //(2^30)-1
    for(int i=0; i<6; ++i) {
        if (r < dist[i]) return data[i];
    }
    return data[6];
}
```

This will be MUCH faster to initialize, MUCH smaller, and probably faster.
Note that even with six digits of accuracy, that last one wouldn't appear ever.  I fudged it's odds up to the minimum to show.

Comment: For people wondering at the `((rand() * RAND_MAX) ^ rand()) & 0x3FFFFFFF;`, that'll generate 30 random bits guaranteed, even if `RAND_MAX` is 32768, 35000, or 2^64.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the purpose of your 1,000,000-element array, it's impossible to know for sure what results you need.

It sounds like there is a value associated with each probability, and you want to make an array that contains only those values, with the distribution determined by their probabilities.

If you want the **exact same** count of each value every time, then it probably ends up reducing to some kind of NP-hard integer problem that minimizes sum({*p* * 1000000 for each *p* in probabilities}).

However, if you can deal with some randomness - then you just need to create a random sampling from your distribution.  First calculate the cumulative distribution function, which is simply a "running total" of your probabilities.  In this case it would be:

```
0.00177277097
0.00177277097 + 0.194862351
0.00177277097 + 0.194862351 + 0.622589724
...
1
```

Then for each slot in the array, get a random number between 0 and 1.  Simply find which two cumulative values it lies between in your distribution and insert the corresponding value.

Answer (score -1):

Well I don't quite understand what you want to do but I can help you with the array part.
Instead of having an array read up on std::vector. It can be used like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::vector<double> vec;
  vec.push_back(0.00112);
  vec.push_back(0.12311);
  ...


  //To access the vector you can use vec[index-you-want]
  std::cout << vec[0]; //prints the first element "0.00112"
}
```

It will grow as you add elements to it. Just read about std::vector. It is great.

Good luck!

Comment: And what if you only push 999994? This doesn't really solve anything.

Comment: @Pubby When I first answered the question it was not clear what the question was. It has been edited and updated since. So my example was just an example of how he could dispose of some problems when using  arrays i.e float a[1000000]. I removed the part you referred to.